# loading a html file from resources into webview applescript

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

I would like to load a local html file from resources into a web view in a applescript objc app.
I have added the files to the bundled resources but I'm not sure how to load them into the web view with something like

```
tell myWebView to setMainFrameURL_("file.html")
```

sorry for the trivial question, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I was looking for a solution in applescript-objc

Answer (score 0):

To get this work you have to

1. Add the **WebKit.framework** to the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section in your apps **General Settings**. Without this I ended up with the error ***cannot decode object of class (WebView)***
2. Create an Outlet. This is necessary to let your Applescript talk to UI elements.

   1. Write `property myWebView : missing value` in your **AppDelegate.applescript** and save it.
   2. Using the Interface Builder view connect (CTRL-drag) the **App Delegate** with your **Web View** and select **myWebView**.
   3. Now the **property myWebView** points directly to your Web View.
3. Tell the WebView to load your HTML file from the app's resources folder:

   ```
   set appResourcesPosixPath to POSIX PATH of (path to current application as text) & "Contents/Resources/"
   tell myWebView to setMainFrameURL_(appResourcesPosixPath & "File.html")
   ```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg